# Clean docs in collection by comparing them with reference

Tags: mongodb

I have a lot of complex JSON objects which are placed in the collection. For example:

```
{
    "name": "Mike",
    "price": "444",
    "distance": 881,
    "someFiend": 123,
    "lots": [
        {
            "aa": "111",
            "bb": "222"
        },
        {
            "xx": "000"
        }
    ],
    "apps": [
        {
            "app": 1
        },
        {
            "app": 2
        }
    ]
}
```

I only want to project only those fields which are present in the following reference document:

```
{
  "name": "",
  "price": "",
  "lots": [
    {
      "aa": "",
      "bb": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

**Expected output:**

```
{
    "name": "Mike",
    "price": "444",
    "lots": [
        {
            "aa": "111",
            "bb": "222"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Is there any way to iterate all documents in the collection and then filter out fields that are not present in the reference doc?**

Comment: Please add expected output

Comment: Yes, it's called [projection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/).

Comment: Do you sure that I can use reference doc with blank values?

Comment: I am sure you need to read the docs to learn how it works.